# TextButton reduces size of child?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I had implemented a column which has a padding of 16px horizontally, and a child container being one of the children. However, i wanted the whole container to be click-able so wrapped it with a TextButton, as a result its width shrunk somewhat, what can i do to restore it back to original while keeping the entire container as a Button?

Here is the code for the concerned widget:

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("Add an item",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 34,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            letterSpacing: -1.5)),
                    Expanded(child: SizedBox(width: 1))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextButton(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 460,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.image_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the TextButton with GestureDetector, like:

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("Add an item",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 34,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            letterSpacing: -1.5)),
                    Expanded(child: SizedBox(width: 1))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 460,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.image_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap:(){}
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

it would look something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! i didnt know GestureDetector doesnt affect dimensions of child. Would you recommend that i always use it when dealing with compound widgets like the above case?

Comment: Yes I would say so, I always use it in cases like this.